# Spring Security AuthenticationManager set a PasswordEncoder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using SpringBoot 2.3.1.RELEASE with Java 14.

I have Spring Security working correctly, i.e. it can receive a username & password and return a jwt token. Various api calls are validated successfully against the token.

Here is my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("datasource1")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
        .usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, password, (NOT disabled) as enabled FROM members "+
                "WHERE username = ?")
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT m.username, t.name as authority FROM members m " +
                "JOIN administrator a ON a.member_id = m.member_id " +
                "JOIN admin_type t ON t.admin_type_id = a.admin_type_id "+
                "WHERE m.username = ?");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // set up the jwt auth
        http.cors().disable();
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll()//.anyRequest().authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .and().exceptionHandling()
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS); // don't manage sessions, using jwt
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        // define the role mappings
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin").hasAuthority("approver admin")
                .antMatchers("/approvals").hasAuthority("approver admin")
                //.antMatchers("/rest/*").hasAuthority("approver admin")
                .antMatchers("/hello").permitAll();

        // INSERT INTO admin_type (admin_type_id, name, description) VALUES ((SELECT MAX(admin_type_id) +1 FROM admin_type), 'approver admin', 'Able to alter approval requests');
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new NexctPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

I also have a RESTful Resource. This receives an `AuthenticationRequest` containing a username and raw password.

**ApprovalsResource.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest) throws Exception {
    try {
        authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword())
        );
    } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
        logger.info("Incorrect username or password for "+authenticationRequest.getUsername());
        throw new Exception("Incorrect username or password", e);
    }
    final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());
    final String jwt = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);
    final String username = jwtTokenUtil.extractUserName(jwt);
    logger.info("User just logged in: "+username);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new AuthenticationResponse(jwt));
}
```

**NexctPasswordEncoder.java**

```
public class NexctPasswordEncoder implements PasswordEncoder {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NexctPasswordEncoder.class);

    @Override
    public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword) {
        return encodeString(rawPassword.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {
        String encoded = encodeString(rawPassword.toString());
        boolean match = encoded.equals(encodedPassword);
        return match;
    }

    private String encodeString(String s) {
        String encryptedPassword = null;
        try {
            MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-384");
            byte[] pt = s.getBytes();
            byte[] out = messageDigest.digest(pt);
            encryptedPassword = HexConvert.ByteToHexString(out);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            logger.error("Error trying to encode password");
        }
        return encryptedPassword;
    }
}
```

This all works perfectly with the `NexctPasswordEncoder` when a raw (unencrypted) password is received. The `NexctPasswordEncoder` encrypts the password to be compared it to the encrypted password in the database.

**Problem**

I also need to cater for the case when I receive the encrypted password rather then the raw password.

**Solution**

I need to get the above to work with two different `PasswordEncoder`'s.

Ideally, in the `ApprovalsResource` where the request with the username and password is received, and the  following is called:

```
authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword())
```

I would like to set the relevant `PasswordEncoder` (one that encrypts the password and one that does not).

**Question**

How do I swap the `PasswordEncoder` depending on a parameter from the request?

Comment: `NexctPasswordEncoder` is my own implementation, I have now added it to the question.

Comment: It doesn't use any prefix.  The passwords are already stored in the database from another application.  Does that mean, when I query the passwords from teh database, I need to add a prefix? here `.usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, password, (NOT disabled) as enabled FROM members "+
                "WHERE username = ?")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Actually solution is very simple.**

> You can't use DelegatePasswordEncoder. Because passwords need to be stored with prefix. And when they stored with prefix, spring security will use the password encoder for that prefix.

**You can do one of the following:**

- Enhance your PasswordEncoder to do plain match as well as encoded match.
- Create a wrapper for NexctPasswordEncoder which will do exact match and then inject it as password encoder. `boolean match = encoded.equals(encodedPassword) || rawPassword.equals(encodedPassword);`

```
public class NexctPasswordEncoder implements PasswordEncoder {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NexctPasswordEncoder.class);

    @Override
    public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword) {
        return encodeString(rawPassword.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {
        String encoded = encodeString(rawPassword.toString());
        boolean match = encoded.equals(encodedPassword) || rawPassword.equals(encodedPassword);
        return match;
    }

    private String encodeString(String s) {
        String encryptedPassword = null;
        try {
            MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-384");
            byte[] pt = s.getBytes();
            byte[] out = messageDigest.digest(pt);
            encryptedPassword = HexConvert.ByteToHexString(out);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            logger.error("Error trying to encode password");
        }
        return encryptedPassword;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would still prefer using this **updated** `NexctPasswordEncoder` as part of DelegatePasswordEncoder if migrating the existing passwords to have a prefix is under your control. Because it allows Bcrypt or anyother encoder to co-exist in the future with the encoders you used in the past

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the DelegatingPasswordEncoder: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/DelegatingPasswordEncoder.html

It allows to determine which other PasswordEncoder to use based on a prefix in the password value.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look

Comment: I have added the following to the SecurityConfig.configure method:  `Map<String, PasswordEncoder> encoders = new HashMap<>();
        encoders.put("nexctCrypt", new NexctPasswordEncoder());
        PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new DelegatingPasswordEncoder("nexctcrypt", encoders);
`.  So where do I add the `"nexctCrypt"` prefix?  Do I prepend it to the front of the password when I extract it from the RESTful service? Here:  `authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword())`.

Comment: Also, if I want an encode that does not encrypt the password, do I still implement the `PasswordEncoder`, but just return the unencrypted password?

Comment: I am obviously mapping the prefix incorrectly, because I get: `There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id \"null\"\n\tat `.  When I try do the following in the resource: `authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), "{nexctCrypt}"+authenticationRequest.getPassword())`.

Comment: @Richard I haven't used it myself yet, but if I'm not mistaken it assumes the prefix in the password it compares against not the one that comes in from the request. So you'd likely need to modify the way you get the stored password. Which may make it a bit tough for you as you seem to fetch everything at once if I see that correctly.

Comment: The password in the database is always stored as encrypted. So when I do the match, I always match two encrypted strings. In my existing implementation, I match the database password with one I receive from the resource (rest) which I encrypt. So I need another Password encoder where I don't encrypt the already encrypted password I receive from the resource. My confusion is, depending on my incoming rest request, how do I choose which PasswordEncoder to use?

Comment: Well you could implement your own one that then also delegates to whichever you need based on a similar scheme as the DelegatingPasswordEncoder just based on the incoming parameter rather than the stored password.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-security-and-custom-passwordnbspencoding

Comment: thanks but this is just an example with one custom encoder, which I am doing already.  I need a second encoder, and to know how to choose between the two.